# How to create & upload to Zbera thermal printer a bitmap font for ZPL language?

Tags: fonts, zebra-printers, zpl, bitmap-fonts

Could You please tell me what is the procedure to create(upload), a bitmap font for ZPL language to Zebra Thermal printer?

It turned out that Zebra doesn't support their clients with bitmap fonts in different code pages. They only have scalable fonts available in their fontpack.

Is it possible to create or convert windows bitmap font to FNT file and use it in ZPL language?

Answer (score 0):

You can find instructions for uploading fonts from your PC to a Zebra printer at Zebra's knowledgebase: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=answeropen&type=open&searchid=1362935480906&answerid=16777218&iqaction=5&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkm.zebra.com%2Fkb%2Findex%3Fpage%3Dcontent%26id%3DSO7889%26actp%3Dsearch%26viewlocale%3Den_US&highlightinfo=6292308,82,99#.

Be careful - there are legal concerns when taking copyrighted fonts (Arial, for example) and loading them to a printer.  Make sure to use a font you have a license to use commercially or use a free font (I believe Google offers many free ones).

Comment: As far as I know the procedure you mentioned in the above link regards font uploading for CPCL language. The font being created on Zebra doesn't have FNT extension and so it cannot be used in ZPL language. ZPL is much more flexible and advanced language and for it I would like to have a bitmap font ...

Answer (score 0):

You can download a full Truetype font onto most ZPL printers directly using the ^DY command.  This is the recommended way to do this unless the font is bigger than the printer's usable storage.  You would have to check the printer's User Guide to find out how much storage your printer has.  This is not usually an issue unless you are working with Asian fonts or older printer models.  In that case, you can use the Font Wizard that comes with [Zebra Setup Utility](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/zebralink/zebra-setup-utility.html) to make the font smaller by selecting only the characters you need. This converts it to a FNT font as well.  The direct method will allow you to call the font as a TTF or OTF.

```
~DYE:MyFont,B,T,XXSIZE,,...binary data of full font
```

Details: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf?page=164

Like Jason mentions, Please remember to make sure your font is licensed to you for this use.